# Google Spreadsheet Email If

Tags: forms, email

First, I am a complete beginner and have no idea what I am doing.

I am wanting to take a form that is submitted in Google forms and email the data to certain individuals.  I got an example code from http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884.

I changed the email and I got this to work.  However now I would like to add a simple if statement so that depending on the first question in the from Who would you like to contact? it will send the email to different email address per different answer. Note: there are more than two choices so I imagine I will need more than one else statement.

I think I need something like this, but I am not sure how to make it work.
 if(e.parameter.source == "Info") sendto = "bob@yahoo.com" else sendto = "bob@email.com"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add the if else block where "source" is the name of the form field:

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

if(e.parameter.source == "Info") 
  email = "bob@yahoo.com" 
else if (e.parameter.source == "Info2")
  email = "bob2@email.com"
else 
  email = "bob2@email.com"
```

Comment: Okay I attempted to implement this, could not get it to work.  Do I need to add any other code to set the source or am I replacing .source with ."name_of_form_field". Thank you ahead of time